# JQuery Animate Height to 100%

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-animate

I want to animate a menu (DIV) from height of 0% to 100% and vice versa. The **hide menu** code works. However, the **show menu** code simple fades in the element with a height of 100%. I want it to grow from 0% to 100%. Any ideas on how to solve this? I am fairly new to JQuery.

JavaScript/JQuery

```html
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#mobileMenu-icon').click(function(){
        if ($('.LEFTNAV-content').hasClass("hide-menu")){
        // Show menu
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').animate({'height':'100%'}, {queue: false});
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').fadeIn('normal');
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').removeClass('hide-menu');
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').addClass('show-menu');
        }
        else{
        // hide menu
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').animate({'height':"1px"}, {queue: false});
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').fadeOut('normal');
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').removeClass('show-menu');
            $('.LEFTNAV-content').addClass('hide-menu');
        }
    })
});
```

CSS

```html
.column-wrapper{ height: auto; }

.LEFTNAV-content{
    display:none; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hide-menu{ display: none; }

.show-menu{
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
}
.box1{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
.innerBox1{
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: none !important;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="column-wrapper">

    <div class="LEFTNAV-content">
        <div class="box1">
            ... menu content ...
            <div class="innerBox1">...some stuff...</div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Body-content">
    ... content ...
    </div>

    <div class="Other-content">
    ... content ...
    </div>

</div>
```

Menu Button (Image)

```html
<div>
<img id="mobileMenu-icon" src="/gif-new/buttons/mobile-Menu.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead of `.animate()`..
For the fade in and out effect use `.animate()` instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

```
$('.LEFTNAV-content').slideDown();
$('.LEFTNAV-content').animate({opacity: 1},{queue: false});
```

and for the hide menu part: [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

```
$('.LEFTNAV-content').slideUp();
$('.LEFTNAV-content').animate({opacity: 0},{queue: false});
```

Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Smy/1/) - I also fixed the problem where the first click has no effect

Comment: Your code worked on jsFiddle but not my Web page(s). Therefore, I included omitted code in the CSS and HTML block. I hope you can solve this. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Smy/1/) with the new HTML and CSS however it seems to still work fine. maybe some other stuff on your website causing this not to work? have you checkd you console for errors?

Comment: I just read a user's notes on another Web site: min-heights can affect slideDown()  [http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slideup-slow-and-slidedown-slow-happening-instantly]

Comment: then try to remove your `min-height` and see if it works. if it does try something else... in my jsFiddle it works fine with `min-height`

Comment: SOLVED!!  The Show-menu class had a height set to 1px; I removed it.